# serial number on the table in codeigniter pagination libarary

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

I have problems when numbering the tables using CodeIgniter framework with libraary pagination. below are the table..

```
+------------------------------------------+
| num| NIP    | Name   | Category  | Type  |
+------------------------------------------+
| 1  | 12345  | udin   | A         |  A1   |
+------------------------------------------+
|    |        |        | B         |  B1   |
+------------------------------------------+
|    |        |        | C         |  C1   |
+------------------------------------------+
| 2  | 54321  | JHON   | B         |  B2   |
+------------------------------------------+
|    |        |        | C         |  C1   |
+------------------------------------------+
```

the issue is on the next page in the table below..

```
+------------------------------------------+
| num| NIP    | Name   | Category  | Type  |
+------------------------------------------+
| 1  | 54321  | JHON   | F         |  F2   |
+------------------------------------------+
|    |        |        | G         |  G3   |
+------------------------------------------+
|    |        |        | G         |  G4   |
+------------------------------------------+
|    |        |        | I         |  I3   |
+------------------------------------------+
|    |        |        | J         |  J1   |
+------------------------------------------+
```

I want the next page numbering sequential numbering starting from the end of the previous value. Supposedly in figure 2 numbering number "2" instead of "1".

code in the controller:

```
$this->load->library('pagination');
$data['judul'] = 'Report Data Attachment';
$start_row = $this->uri->segment(3);
$per_page = 10; 

        if (trim($this->uri->segment(3)) == '')
        {
            $start_row = '0';
        }
    $config['base_url'] = base_url().'report/index/';
    $config['total_rows'] = $this->lampiran_m->lampiran_karyawan_semua_page_conter()->num_rows();
    //$config['uri_segment'] = '3';
    $config['per_page'] = $per_page;
    $config['full_tag_open'] = '<p class="page">';
    $config['full_tag_close'] = '</p>';       
      $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    $data['pagination'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
     $data['lampiran'] = $this->lampiran_m->lampiran_karyawan_semua_page($start_row,','.$per_page);



        $data['no'] = '';
     $data['last'] = '';

     $this->template->display('tabel_report',$data);
```

and code in my Model :

```
public function lampiran_karyawan_semua_page($offset='',$limit='')
{
    $qry = "select distinct lampiran.id_category,name_category,tipe,lampiran.nip from lampiran
    left join employee on (lampiran.nip = employee.nip)
    left join category on (lampiran.id_category=category.id_category) where lampiran.id_category = category.id_category and lampiran.nip=employee.nip  order by lampiran.nip desc limit $offset $limit";
    return $this->db->query($qry);
}
```

and this code in view :

```
<table border="1" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="product-table" >
            <tr>
            <th class="table-header-repeat line-left minwidth-1"> <a href="#mainform">No</a></th>
                <th class="table-header-repeat line-left minwidth-1"> <a href="#mainform">NIP</a></th>
                <th class="table-header-repeat line-left minwidth-1"> <a href="#mainform">Name</a></th>
                <th class="table-header-repeat line-left minwidth-1"> <a href="#mainform">Category Attachment</a></th>
                <th class="table-header-repeat line-left minwidth-1"><a href="#mainform">Type Attachment</a>    </th>
                <th class="table-header-repeat line-left minwidth-1"><a href="#mainform">Page</a>   </th>

            </tr>
            <?php 


                    foreach($lampiran->result_array() as  $k) {

             $now=$k['nip'];
              if($last!=$now )  {
                $no++;
              echo "<tr><td>$no</td><td>$k[nip]</td><td>".$this->employee_m->get($k['nip'])->nama."</td><td>$k[name_category]</td><td>$k[tipe]</td><td>"; ?>
              <?php foreach($this->lampiran_m->conter_tabel_semua($k['id_category'],$k['tipe'],$k['nip'])->result() as $row) :?>
                        <?php echo $row->nilai;?>
                    <?php endforeach; 
              echo "</td></tr>";

              }else{

              echo "<tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>$k[name_category]</td><td>$k[tipe]</td><td>"; ?>
              <?php foreach($this->lampiran_m->conter_tabel_semua($k['id_category'],$k['tipe'],$k['nip'])->result() as $row) :?>
                        <?php echo $row->nilai;?>
                    <?php endforeach; 
              echo "</td></tr>";
              }
             $last = $k['nip'];

             }
            ?>
           <tr><td colspan="5" style="text-align: center;"><b>Jumlah Total</b></td><td>
                <?php foreach($this->lampiran_m->jumlah_semua_lampiran()->result() as $row) :?>
                        <?php echo "<b>$row->jumlah</b>";?>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
           </td></tr>

            </table>
```

I hope someone can help me on this issue .. thanks

Answer (score 3):

before foreach you have to add

$no = $this->uri->segment(3)+1;

No
                 NIP
                 Name
                 Category Attachment
                Type Attachment    
                Page

```
        </tr>
        <?php 

            //before foreach you have to add 
            $no = $this->uri->segment(3)+1;
                foreach($lampiran->result_array() as  $k) {

         $now=$k['nip'];
          if($last!=$now )  {
            $no++; 
          echo "<tr><td>$no</td><td>$k[nip]</td><td>".$this->employee_m->get($k['nip'])->nama."</td><td>$k[name_category]</td><td>$k[tipe]</td><td>"; ?>
          <?php foreach($this->lampiran_m->conter_tabel_semua($k['id_category'],$k['tipe'],$k['nip'])->result() as $row) :?>
                    <?php echo $row->nilai;?>
                <?php endforeach; 
          echo "</td></tr>";

          }else{

          echo "<tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>$k[name_category]</td><td>$k[tipe]</td><td>"; ?>
          <?php foreach($this->lampiran_m->conter_tabel_semua($k['id_category'],$k['tipe'],$k['nip'])->result() as $row) :?>
                    <?php echo $row->nilai;?>
                <?php endforeach; 
          echo "</td></tr>";
          }
         $last = $k['nip'];

         }
        ?>
       <tr><td colspan="5" style="text-align: center;"><b>Jumlah Total</b></td><td>
            <?php foreach($this->lampiran_m->jumlah_semua_lampiran()->result() as $row) :?>
                    <?php echo "<b>$row->jumlah</b>";?>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
       </td></tr>

        </table>
```

Comment: both of u have done wonderful work thanks a lot but if you start count before first echo ur count will start with 2 rather than 1

Answer (score 2):

please put below line before foreach statement

```
$currentffset = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;
$slno_start = (($currentffset / $per_page) * per_page) + 1;
```

after that use $slno_start as serial number for each item inside foreach at last line of foreach just increment it

```
$slno_start++;
```

Answer (score 1):

Minor improvement from above answers.Thanks both of u guys

```
$count =$this->uri->segment(3)+1;
foreach($records as $rec){echo $count; $count++;}
```